# Populating a listview from a SQLite database

Tags: android, database, listview, populate, items

I have an activity where i write a name which is insert in the database. In another activity  I want to put a ListView which is populated with those names which are in the database or to add the new item directly when i write it in the edittext from the first activity.
    I realized the insert into database part but i can't figure out how to populate that listview.

```
public class Add extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button sqlUpdate;
EditText sqlName;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add);
    sqlUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bFinishAdd);
    //sqlView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSQLopenView);
    sqlName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAdd);
    sqlUpdate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean didItWork = true;

            try{
            String name = sqlName.getText().toString();

            DBhelp entry = new DBhelp(Add.this);
            entry.open();
            entry.createEntry(name);
            entry.close();
            Intent i = new Intent(Add.this, Liste.class);
            startActivity(i);

            }catch(Exception i){
                didItWork = false;
            }finally{
        }
        }


    });

}


public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Here is the database helper:

```
      public class DBhelp {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "persons_name";



private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DBhelpdb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "peopleTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;


private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);"


        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public DBhelp(Context c){
    ourContext = c;
}
public DBhelp open() throws SQLException{
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}
public void createEntry(String name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);

    ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}
public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName) + "\n";
    }

    return result;
}
public String getName(long l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);
    if (c!=null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String name = c.getString(1);
        return name;
    }
    return null;
}

public void updateEntry(long lRow, String mName) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_NAME, mName);
    ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_ROWID + "=" + lRow, null);
}
public void deteleEntry(long lRow1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + lRow1, null);}
}
```

And here is the activity where I want to implement the listview with that items  :

```
     public class Liste extends Activity{

Button btnAdd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.liste);
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent("com.project.mapshop.ADD");
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSQLinfo);
    DBhelp info = new DBhelp(this);
    info.open();
    String data = info.getData();
    info.close();
    tv.setText(data);

}}
```

I would be very grateful if you could explain me how to do it or give me a link with an advice or tutorial which could help me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please follow some simple tutorials first, some good tutorials are:

1- [Simple Example](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/06/simple-example-using-androids-sqlite_02.html)

2- [ListView of Data from SQLiteDatabase](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2011/02/listview-of-data-from-sqlitedatabase.html)

Comment: This is a perfect example of why you shouldn't just use links as an answer, the first of these three no longer exist.

Answer (score 3):

As you requested, here is a very thorough tutorial which I believe will answer your questions: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#overview.

It explains you how to set a `ListActivity` and then creating your very own adapter to populate the list.

Hope it helps!