# I delete an entry in SQLite database, then I got mixed order in ListView?

Tags: android

Hi I am making an app where I execute in the MainActivity a line of code like

```
ArrayList<Notes> array_list = mydb.getAllNotes();
```

here I get all rows in the database but then I have an option to delete one and I do it, when I do it it deletes that row in the database and then to go back to the main activity I execute code like:

```
mydb.deleteById(id_to_delete_update);
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Where the very first line of code gets executed and we can see all entries but not in proper order for example if I delete the first , go back to the main activity it looks like the second one stays at the place of the first one  and when I press it to get info from the database for it, I send the position +1, but that's not right because that record in the database is number 2, and I am looking for record 1 which actually I just deleted. Please help with some advice.

Comment: Please confirm this for me, are you using the position of the item on your list as its record ID in the database for lookup?

Comment: I look up using the position, but the problem is it is already deleted for example

Comment: Positions don't matter, there are no positions in databases. You need unique IDs to be able to find the data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ListView` use `RecyclerView`

In your Database table Create one extra column for id which should be primary(Also use Auto Increament). Now while deleting a entry from database use below code.

```
    mydb.delete(table_name, id + " = " + number , null);

// where number is the id of your entry which you want to delete
```

and for getting an specific entry use below code

```
    Cursor c = mydb.rawQuery(SELECT * FROM  table_name WHERE id + " = " + number , null);

// where number is the id of your entry which you want to get detail
```

Comment: that's not the problem, the problem is more in the ListView,

Comment: With the advent of Android Lollipop, the RecyclerView made its way officially. The RecyclerView is much more powerful, flexible and a major enhancement over ListView. I will try to give you a detailed insight into it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are looking up using the `position` in the `List` - when you delete an entry in the database, the record IDs do not get rearranged - so if you had record IDs `(1,2,3,4)` when you delete record `ID 1`, you remain with `2,3,4` - note that `ID 2` does not become `ID 1`. You need to use the actual IDs (usually `primary keys` in your database) to look-up and not its position - because the positions have no meaning in the database.

For examples on how to populate your `Listview` with data from the database, please check the [following tutorial/example](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.co.za/2011/02/listview-of-data-from-sqlitedatabase.html) as well as [this tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/android/learn-how-to-create-listview-from-sqlite-database-in-android-development/) - I also strongly suggest you look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656901/populating-a-listview-from-a-sqlite-database)