# how to save the data which are dynamically added in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am developing one small application where i am adding items one by one in the recyclerview if the user click on the '+' symbol in the menu bar.

[image: This is my app where am adding items in recyclerview]

The problem is i want to save the data(items) permanently in recyclerview even we close the app.So that the user can come again and edit the item which are in recyclerview.

Kindly let me know how can i achieve this since i am new to this..Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: you can use Database in your app to persist data, or you can store it in file or SharedPreference, but Database is more better.

Comment: use sqlite to save data and show when application loads

Comment: you can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656901/populating-a-listview-from-a-sqlite-database

Comment: see these examples to use sqlite database.. http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the lots of option available to store data in locally or live,

- One is store in Preference help of json or normaly,
- Second way is store inside of local Database like SQLLite or also Realme is available,
- Third way is store it online help of server or directly using firebase,
- Another way is store it in file, and read and write and edit,

I am suggesting if your data size is small then store with Preference  and data size is big then take data base and if you dont want to store locally then you can take help of firebase or web service.

Answer (score 0):

to do this you have several options :

1- save in ***SharedPreferences***

2- use ***DataBase*** : [sqliteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)   or [Realm](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj7m6nisNXSAhXL8RQKHbmZARIQFghIMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Frealm.io%2F&usg=AFQjCNG1RvoGEzr_PxQk-Jn539jP6xXJug&sig2=fuNXfInvBXGZMnsmQT3u1g)

3- write in ***File***